# Bootstrap: Change container order on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I'm facing a bootstrap problem.

In my html page, I used different containers but I'm not able to re-arrange and re-organize them as I want in mobile screens.

[Here my Bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/UU2lPsJylm)

And to be more clear, I want it to look like this:

[image]

Containers 1 and 5 are fluid, instead 2, 3, 4 are not.

How can I move container 1 and 2 after 3 and 4 in small screens?

Thank you in advance for your reply!

Cheers!

Comment: Not with Bootstrap (AFAIK)...`flexbox` can do that though.

Comment: flex, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flexbox` proof of concept.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  padding: .25em;
}
.page {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  flex: 0 0 75px;
  background: darkgreen;
}
.banner {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: darkred;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  width: 75%;
  background: yellow;
}
aside {
  width: 25%;
  background: fuchsia;
}
footer {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .banner,
  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
    order: -1;
  }
  .content,
  aside {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  aside {
    flex: 0 0 150px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header>
    <h2>1</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="banner">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <main>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>4</h2>
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h2>5</h2>
  </footer>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WvBKrq?editors=110)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without rearranging your content.

One way is to make two versions of the area you want to rearrange and hide them based on the width of the browser. This is bad practice, especially if you have a whole website you want to rearrange on resize, but for a small div with 5 divs inside it would be an acceptable solution.

Here is the adapted HTML

```
<div class="desktopwrapper"> <!-- added a desktop wrapper -->
  <div class="container-fluid green"></div>
  <div class="container red"></div>
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 yellow"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 fuxia"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="mobilewrapper"> <!-- added a mobile wrapper and rearranged content -->
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 yellow"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 fuxia"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid green"></div>
  <div class="container red"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid blue"></div>
</div>
```

And I have added these lines to CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .desktopwrapper {
      display:none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .mobilewrapper {
      display:none;
  }
}
```

What this basically does, is hide one arrangement when the screen gets resized to 766px wide and will display the other. And of course the other way around.

You can try it out [here](http://codepen.io/rvervuurt/pen/EjzREj).

Another way would be to put everything in a wrapper, `position` the wrapper `relative`, all the divs inside `absolute` and just place them with using px. This is however really not useful when divs have changing heights depending on the content. The best way would be to do like the example I have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I would avoid duplicated code.